# GitHub get commits number using python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the number of commits of github repos using python and beautiful soup

html code:

```
<div class="flex-shrink-0">
        <h2 class="sr-only">Git stats</h2>
        <ul class="list-style-none d-flex">
          <li class="ml-0 ml-md-3">
            <a data-pjax href="..." class="pl-3 pr-3 py-3 p-md-0 mt-n3 mb-n3 mr-n3 m-md-0 Link--primary no-underline no-wrap">
              <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">
                    <strong>26</strong>
                    <span aria-label="Commits on master" class="color-text-secondary d-none d-lg-inline">
                      commits
                    </span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

my code:

```
r = requests.get(source_code_link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        spans = soup.find_all('span', class_='d-none d-sm-inline')
        for span in spans:
            number = span.select_one('strong')
```

sometimes works but sometimes no because there are more then one `span` tag with class `d-none d-sm-inline`.
how can i solve ?

Comment: can you share the HTML for more than one span tag for understanding!

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Github has an extensive and powerful api that would be drastically easier to use for this purpose unless you're specifially trying to learn beautifulsoup

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use the API? Say this get request: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-commits

Comment: i had tried to use the API but they don't return the desired value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html="""<span class="d-none d-sm-inline">
               
                    <strong>26</strong>
                    <span aria-label="Commits on master" class="color-text-secondary d-none d-lg-inline">
                      commits
                    </span>
              </span>
              <div class="flex-shrink-0">
        <h2 class="sr-only">Git stats</h2>
        <ul class="list-style-none d-flex">
          <li class="ml-0 ml-md-3">
            <a data-pjax href="..." class="pl-3 pr-3 py-3 p-md-0 mt-n3 mb-n3 mr-n3 m-md-0 Link--primary no-underline no-wrap">
              <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">
                    <strong>23</strong>
                    <span aria-label="Commits on master" class="color-text-secondary d-none d-lg-inline">
                      commits
                    </span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>"""
```

I have combine both example which look up for tag `strong` and based on that prints data by using `.contents` method

```
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
spans = soup.find_all('span', class_='d-none d-sm-inline')
for span in spans:
    for tag in span.contents:
        if tag.name=="strong" :
            print(tag.get_text())
```

using  list comprehension :

```
for span in spans:
   data=[tag for tag in span.contents if tag.name=="strong"]
   print(data[0].get_text())
```

Ouput for both case:

```
26
23
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using [list commits](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-commits) from GitHub's REST API

```
import requests

user = ... # username or organisation
repo = ... # repository name

response = requests.get(f"https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo}/commits")
if response.ok:
    ncommits = len(response.json())
else:
    raise ValueError(f"error: {response.url} responded {response.reason}")

print(ncommits)
```

Comment: i had tried to use the API but they don't return the desired value

Comment: If you don't give more details, it's difficult to suggest anything.  Which repo are you trying with? What is incorrect about the response from the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method to look for a `<strong>` after the class `d-none d-sm-inline`.

In your case:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all("span", class_="d-none d-sm-inline"):
    print(tag.find_next("strong").text)
```